# DataSource.getConnection method returns an already closed connection after database restart or ideal timeout

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc, datasource

Here is my code to obtain database `Connection` from `DataSource`

```
DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().url(url).username(userName).password(password).driverClassName(dataSourceReader.getSqlServerDriverClassName()).build();
Connection connection  = dataSource.getConnection();
System.out.println(connection.isClosed()); //Print false
```

Everything is working fine if continuous database operation happens.
If I put my application ideal for some time(connection timeout) or I restart my database server and try to execute same above code, I get closed connection and output of `connection.isClosed()` is true,
Further, if I perform any operation on `connection` it throws below exception

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:388) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareCall(SQLServerConnection.java:2176) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareCall(SQLServerConnection.java:1861) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor148.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar!/:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.prepareCall(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
```

Surprisingly, the same code works fine after restarting my java application.

Any suggestion to handle this situation?

Can I reopen closed connection?

More details:

- Java version: 1.8.0_25
- Application Server: Tomcat 8 with Spring Boot
- Database: Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit) Version 10.50.1617.0
- Database driver:`com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be robust, your application should be designed to handle connection exceptions because they can (and do) occur for many reasons in an enterprise environment.  One way to handle this is to simply catch the sql exception from the connection object and try to get a connection again until you're successful or you're reached some retry limit you've set.  Depending on the environment and whether the jdbc driver or app server is performing connection pooling, you may need to retry until the pool purges itself of failed connections.  You probably want to limit your retries to the size of any connection pool so you don't loop indefinitely.

Comment: I used `BasicDataSource` of dbcp and it works after connection timeout and database restart. It solve my problem